# Nesting Sphinx extension directives with reST

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to nest Sphinx extension directives. I have a few custom node types that are working great, but I'd like a little more flexibility in the HTML I'm generating.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

Say I have a directive that creates a textbox and button that triggers some JavaScript. This works fine - I can put this in my reST file:

```
.. myDirective:: name
    :opt1: val
    content
```

Now, I want the ability to create a tabbed interface with jQuery in the output. I have a node type that creates the raw HTML/JavaScript needed for this to happen.

What I would like to be able to do is give the tab node 1 or more instances of myDirective (or other directives), and have it put each instance into another tab. Something like this:

```
..tabbedInterface:: 
    .. myDirective:: name1
        :op1: val1
        content

    .. myDirective:: name2
        :op1: val1
        content
```

Obviously this is a pretty specific case, but this is generally what I'd like to accomplish - nested directives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The configuration-block extension might help you :
https://github.com/fabpot/sphinx-php/blob/master/sensio/sphinx/configurationblock.py

From : http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/contributing/documentation/format.html#configuration-blocks

```
.. configuration-block::

  .. code-block:: yaml

    # Configuration in YAML

  .. code-block:: xml

    <!-- Configuration in XML //-->

  .. code-block:: php

    // Configuration in PHP
```

Comment: Thanks! That gave me enough to eventually figure it out.